# actionscript 3 - error #1009 Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3

I've only recently started using as so sorry for this
 as its probably pretty simple. Im basically trying to spawn an AI unit but am getting the error 1009, here is the full error.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at code::Init()[D:\FlashGame\code\Init.as:21]
```

Im trying to use a function from another class which is in another file. Here is the first file.

```
package code
{
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer; 
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;

import code.functions.AIManager;

public class Init extends MovieClip
{
    private var _AI:AIManager;
    private var _player:MovieClip;

    public function Init()
    {
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
        _AI.createAI();
    }

    public function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
    {}
  }
}
```

And the second file..

```
package code.functions
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;

public class AIManager extends MovieClip
{   
    private var _ai:MovieClip;

    public function AIManager()
    {
        createAI();
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
    }

    public function createAI():void
    {           
        _ai = new AI();
        _ai.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        _ai.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        stage.addChild(_ai);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of a class before you can use it's methods. The exception to that is static methods. In your case you just need to use `new AIManager`

```
_AI = new AIManager();
_AI.createAI();
```